# Разница между line box и inline box

Tags: html, css

Случайно где-то в интернете увидел один из терминов. Потом еще покопался и понял что это все таки разные вещи. В спецификации описываются эти термины, но я все же не понял их различия. Если кто-то может, то пусть объяснит доступно и покажет примерами разницу между `line box` и `inline box`.

Comment: Поскольку сам до конца не разобрался с этой темой, лучше вместо ответа будет [ссылка](http://css-live.ru/css/vvedenie-v-inlajnovyj-kontekst-formatirovaniya-ikf-osnovnye-ponyatiya-1-ya-publikaciya-cikla-tajny-css2-1.html)

Comment: @E_K интересная статья, надо прочитать!

Answer (score 0):

## Line box

> The rectangular area that contains the boxes that form a line is called a **line box**.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022042/what-does-mean-line-box-in-css%22%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%22)

Перевод:

> Прямоугольная область, содержащая контейнеры, которые образуют линию,
> называется **line box**.

## Inline box

Элемент к которому применили

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: Насчет line box понятно (хоть я уже до вашего ответа и видел ту ветку и читал спеку как упоминал в вопросе). А что касается inline box - вообще не ясно. С таким успехом я могу сказать что `line box` - `display: inline;` (хотя на самом деле не так)
В целом ответ невнятный, я мало чего понял.

Comment: Inline box это не display: inline-block

Answer (score 0):

> Говоря простым языком, лайн-бокс - это удобный виртуальный контейнер,
> от которого «пляшут» элементы строки (инлайн-боксы). Дело в том, что
> при построении строки рендерер (механизм отрисовки страниц в браузерах
> и построения DOM-дерева) должен как-то узнать, какую Y-координату дать
> следующей порции инлайнового контента (тексту, картинкам и т.п.).
> Можно сказать, что лайн-бокс - это способ учёта пространства по
> вертикали, занимаемого инлайном.

Такое описание дано в книге "Инлайновый контекст форматирования" 2012 года.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).